# Connect to SQL Server hosted in Azure VM from Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to connect from my Power BI desktop to a SQL Server hosted in Azure VM.
I have a gateway in a place where the Power BI Desktop is installed and I am able to connect to the local SQL Server, but cannot connect to the SQL Server hosted in Azure VM.

Do I need to provide a remote connection to SQL Server?
Are there any other settings needed?

Comment: is there a gateway installed on the Azure VM SQL Server?

Comment: Problem solved. No, I didn't installed the gateway on Azure VM. I exposed the SQL port in order to  allow externally connections.